# Can we apply cryptography techniques in MATLAB?

Tags: java, matlab, cryptography, steganography

I am on a project that uses **Steganography**- hiding some data(in my case sound files) in a image. I am using **MATLAB** as the tool. The project is almost done but I need to add a feature to add encryption techniques to it. **Does MATLAB have cryptographic extensions like java?** I tried googling but ended up with programs that implements Algorithms. I need to know if there are some method by which cryptographic algorithms can be used just like in Java.
Thank you..

Answer (score 3):

Every Matlab version is shipped with its own JVM, so you can simply use [Java cryptographic package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html).

You can create a [`Cipher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) like:

```
cipher = javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance('AES');
```

This cipher supports all the standard transformations (AES, DES, RSA ...)

If this package does not contain the functionality that you want, you can add any Java classes in JAR files also to the classpath of the JVM of Matlab by calling [`javaaddpath`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javaaddpath.html). More about this can be found [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html).

If you need more information about using Java in Matlab you can refer to [this article](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html).